# how to modify attribute of an xml node c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to modify an attribute of an xml node. However selecting the attribute is appearing to be a bit more confusing than i thought. Here is my code...

```
element = root.SelectSingleNode "/nexus/category/node[@className='Family']"
attr = element.SelectSingleNode "/nexus/category/node/attributeblocks/attributeblock/attribute[@key='isHidden']"
```

What i don't understand is why i have to define the entire xml tree when selecting the attribute within the selected element. Why can't i write the code like this?

```
element = root.SelectSingleNode "/nexus/category/node[@className='Family']"
attr = element.SelectSingleNode "/node/attributeblocks/attributeblock/attribute[@key='isHidden']"
```

For anyone who is trying to help me out, here is the xml file...

> My ultimate goal: How do i select the Family Node and change the
>   attribute **isHidden** to **true** then copy the new Family node with
>   it's modified data to the clipboard?

I do know when i copy to the clipboard i would use something like `element.OuterXML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE nexus>
<nexus version="1.0">
    <category name="Container">
        <node className="Group Box" virtualName="" image=":/images/icon.ico" enabled="True" backgroundColor="RGBA(255,255,0,255)" isContainer="True">
            <viewblocks>
                <rect x="0.0" y="0.0" width="350" height="250"/>
            </viewblocks>
        </node>
    </category>
    <category name="General">
        <node className="Family" virtualName="Family" image=":/images/icon.ico" enabled="True" backgroundColor="RGBA(0,255,0,255)">
            <viewblocks>
                <rect x="0.0" y="0.0" width="150" height="120"/>
            </viewblocks>
            <inputs>
                <item name="Input 01" type="Kids" limit="2"/>
                <item name="Input 02" type="People"/>
            </inputs>
            <outputs>
                <item name="Output 01" type="Kids" limit="5"/>
                <item name="Output 02" type="People" limit="23"/>
                <item name="Output 03" type="Cars"/>
            </outputs>
            <attributeblocks>
                <attributeblock name = "Basic Properties">
                    <attribute type="boolean" key="isHidden" label="Is Hidden" value="False"/>
                    <attribute type="string" key="nickname" label="Nickname" value="Candy Bar"/>
                </attributeblock>
                <attributeblock name = "User Properties">
                    <attribute type="float" key="average" label="Average" value="20.5" minValue="0.0" maxValue="100.0"/>
                    <attribute type="integer" key="integervalue" label="Integer Value" value="205" minValue="20" maxValue="1000"/>
                </attributeblock>
                <attributeblock name="Cool Stuff">
                    <attribute type="color" key="colorA" label="Color" value="RGBA(0,255,0,255)"/>
                    <attribute type="color" key="colorB" label="Color" value="RGBA(255,0,255,255)"/>
                    <attribute type="color" key="colorC" label="Color" value="RGBA(0,100,200,80)"/>
                </attributeblock>
            </attributeblocks>
        </node>
        <node className="Cops" virtualName="Cops" image=":/images/icon.ico" enabled="True" backgroundColor="RGBA(0,255,0,255)">
            <viewblocks>
                <rect x="0.0" y="0.0" width="100" height="120"/>
            </viewblocks>
            <inputs>
                <item name="Input 01" type="People" limit="3"/>
                <item name="Input 02" type="Cars" limit="2"/>
                <item name="Input 03" type="Kids"/>
            </inputs>
            <outputs>
                <item name="Output 01" type="People" limit="0"/>
                <item name="Output 02" type="Cars" limit="2"/>
            </outputs>
            <attributeblocks>
                <attributeblock name="Cool Stuff">
                    <attribute type="dropdownlist" key="dropdownlist" label="DropDown List" value="Item 5" items="Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4,Item 5"/>
                    <attribute type="folderpath" key="folderpath" label="Folder Path" value=""/>
                    <attribute type="textbox" key="textbox" label="Text Box" value="Joe, Sam, Leslie, Kevin, Michael, Chris"/>
                    <attribute type="filepath" key="filepathopen" label="File Open Path" value="" filter="Files(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg)" method="open"/>
                    <attribute type="filepath" key="filepathsave" label="File Save Path" value="" filter="Files(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg)" method="save"/>
                </attributeblock>
                <attributeblock name = "User Properties">
                    <attribute type="float" key="average" label="Average" value="20.5" minValue="0.0" maxValue="100.0"/>
                    <attribute type="integer" key="integervalue" label="Int Test" value="205" minValue="20" maxValue="1000"/>
                </attributeblock>
            </attributeblocks>
        </node>
    </category>
    <category name="Extra">
        <node className="Schools" virtualName="Schools" image=":/images/icon.ico" enabled="True" backgroundColor="RGBA(0,255,0,255)">
            <viewblocks>
                <rect x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="60"/>
            </viewblocks>
            <inputs>
                <item name="In" type="Kids" limit="2"/>
            </inputs>
            <outputs>
                <item name="Out" type="Kids" limit="4"/>
            </outputs>
            <attributeblocks>
                <attributeblock name = "Basic Properties">
                    <attribute type="boolean" key="isHidden" label="Is Hidden" value="False"/>
                    <attribute type="string" key="nickname" label="Nickname" value="Candy Nick"/>
                </attributeblock>
                <attributeblock name = "User Properties">
                    <attribute type="color" key="color1" label="Test Color" value="ff00ff"/>
                    <attribute type="string" key="nickname" label="Nickname" value="Stefan Hord"/>
                </attributeblock>
            </attributeblocks>
        </node>
        <node className="Workers" virtualName="Workers" image=":/images/icon.ico" enabled="True" backgroundColor="RGBA(0,255,0,255)">
            <viewblocks>
                <rect x="0.0" y="0.0" width="150" height="100"/>
            </viewblocks>
            <inputs>
                <item name="Input 01" type="Kids" limit="2"/>
                <item name="Input 02" type="Cars"/>
                <item name="Input 03" type="Peoples" limit="0"/>
                <item name="Input 04" type="Peoples"/>
            </inputs>
            <outputs>
                <item name="Output 01" type="Kids"/>
                <item name="Output 02" type="Cars" limit="8"/>
                <item name="Output 03" type="Cars" limit="4"/>
                <item name="Output 04" type="Peoples"/>
            </outputs>
            <attributeblocks>
                <attributeblock name = "User Properties">
                    <attribute type="integer" key="integerid" label="Int Text" value="489" minValue="-10" maxValue="23456"/>
                    <attribute type="string" key="nickname" label="Nickname" value="Candy Bar"/>
                </attributeblock>
            </attributeblocks>
        </node>
    </category>
</nexus>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
attr = element.SelectSingleNode "attributeblocks/attributeblock/attribute[@key='isHidden']";
```

Note that it doen't start with a slash `/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication84
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var family = doc.Descendants("node").Where(x => x.Attribute("className").Value == "Family");

            var hidden = family.Descendants("attribute").Where(x => x.Attribute("key").Value == "isHidden").FirstOrDefault();

            hidden.Attribute("value").Value = "True";
        }
    }
}
```